# On Symfony2, What does it mean the dot "." after ressource key in routing_dev.yml?

Tags: symfony, routes

Usually, when i install bundles on symfony2, like sonata bundles or assetic, there is a portion of text that seems odd to me.

For example in routing_dev.yml

```
_assetic:
    resource: .
    type:     assetic
```

Can you explain to us what does it mean the dot "." after ressource key ?

Thak you

Answer (score 1):

both previous answers are wrong.

```
type: assetic
```

... is already enough for symfony to resolve the assetic's asset routes as they are being auto-generated.

Those routes are the ones generated if `assetic.use_controller` is set to `true`.

They are of the following pattern:

```
_assetic_js_bootstrap_1
```

- _assetic is the prefix
- followed by the assetic collection name ( js_bootstrap in this case )
- followed by _# ( where # is the position of the asset in the collection )

The `.` resource is there to prevent the routing config-validation from failing here!

The `.` is always  auto-added if `use_controller` is true and the `router.resource` parameter exists using a compilerpass [here](https://github.com/symfony/AsseticBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Compiler/RouterResourcePass.php#L41).

Answer (score 0):

i think the "." means it is referring to the web folder.

Comment: You should give more details and explain better why do "you think" it is so. Maybe is there some documentation you can link to?

Answer (score 0):

It applies to the current directory. It is the entry point to your application where your app.php (or whatever environment front controller is stored), which is your web folder.